# Can Windows Server 2011 run Adobe products?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, adobe-premiere

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Home Server 2011 as a Desktop OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/356684/windows-home-server-2011-as-a-desktop-os)

I have several AMD and Intel 64bit systems that need a copy of a 64bit Windows to run Adobe CS 5+. To that end, WHS 2011 is about half the price of the Windows 7 Home OS which makes it an attractive alternative.

In addition, it supports data server features which are a big plus if any of the machines need to be retired later on.

Can I use WHS 2011 as a desktop OS for these computers?